# How to pop menu at QTreeWidgetItem‘s coordinates?

Tags: c++, qt, contextmenu, coordinates, qtreewidget

In QT:I craete a QMenu:

```
QMenu* popMenu = new QMenu(ui->treeWidget);
```

and I want to pop it above the current treewidgetitem, but what I only know is:

```
popMenu->exec(QCursor::pos());
```

So if I use:

```
ui->treeWidget->setCurrentItem(treeWidgetItem);//this is necessary for my program and the current item will be used elsewhere.
```

The menu will pop at the pos of the mouse-clicked pos not at the item. This looks wizard:(
How can I pop the menu at the current item’s coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure my solution is quite stupid, but it works:
I measured the root QTreeWidgetItem's height as 15, and child QTreeWidgetItem's height as 12.
The code:

```
bool MainWindow::isAtItemPos()
{
    QPoint treeWidgetPos = ui->treeWidget->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0));
    QPoint curPos = QCursor::pos();
    int verPos = curPos.ry() - treeWidgetPos.ry();
    int verMax = 15 + 12*rootItem->childCount();
    if(verPos <= verMax)return true;
    else return false;
}
```

And I use it:

```
if(isAtItemPos())popMenu->exec(QCursor::pos());
```

It works :)